# Populate hierarchy in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to build a hierarchy and I am using a dictionary.
I read strings randomly when I am trying to build this
and they have this format:

```
address.city.streetname.housenumber

address.areacode

address.city.streetname.coAddress
```

I have a problem figuring out how to populate the entire hierarchy
This is what I have done:

```
public class JsonElement
{
    public string parent { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<JsonElement> childrenJsonElements { get; set; }
}

var dictionaryHierarchy = new Dictionary<string, JsonElement>();

List<string> stringList = new List<string>()
{ "address.city.streetname.housenumber",
   "address.areacode",
   "address.city.streetname.coAddress"};


foreach(string element in stringList)
{
   string[] tagsStringArray = element.Split('.');

   if (!dictionaryHierarchy.ContainsKey(tagsStringArray[0]))
   {
       dictionaryHierarchy.Add(tagsStringArray[0], new JsonElement());
   }

    dictionaryHierarchy = AddElementsToHierarchy();
 }


private static Dictionary<string, JsonElement> AddElementsToHierarchy(Dictionary<string, 
JsonElement> dictionaryHierarchy, string element)
{
    JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonElement();
    string[] tagsStringArray = element.Split('.');

   if (tagsStringArray.Length < 2)
   {
     return dictionaryJsonHierarchy;
   }

   jsonElement = dictionaryHierarchy[tagsStringArray[0]];
   int ix = 1;

   while (ix < tagsStringArray.Length)
   {
      if (jsonElement.name != tagsStringArray[ix])
      {
          jsonElement.parent = tagsStringArray[ix-1];
          jsonElement.name = tagsStringArray[ix];
      }
    else
    {
       ; // This part is for adding children
    }
    
    ix++;
   }

   return dictionaryHierarchy;
 }
```

Comment: I can't understand the role of `dictionaryHierarchy`, because it will only contain a single key `address` in this example.

Comment: I could have written some more examples of the strings I will read:

person.name.firstname
person.name.lastname
location.areacode.zipcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tree structure made up of `JsonElement` nodes. This structure is the only data structure you need. Let's redefine `JsonElement`:

```cs
public class JsonElement
{
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<JsonElement> Children { get; } = new List<JsonElement>();
}
```

We made the properties PascalCase. This is the usual naming convetion. The `Children` are a read-only property with an initializer which instantiates the list.

As suggested, we add some more examples:

```cs
var input = new[] {
    "address.city.streetname.housenumber",
    "address.areacode",
    "address.city.streetname.coAddress",
    "person.name.firstname",
    "person.name.lastname"
};
```

Now, we have two different elements at the start of the hierarchy. To enable this scenario, we add a neutral root element with a `null` name.

```cs
var root = new JsonElement();
foreach (string s in input) {
    AddElements(root, s.Split('.'));
}
```

Now, let's create the hierarchy.

Adding elements consists of walking down the tree structure by following the tags (names). If one is missing, we add it.

```cs
private static void AddElements(JsonElement node, string[] elements)
{
    foreach (string element in elements) {
        var child = node.Children.Find(child => child.Name == element);
        if (child == null) {
            child = new JsonElement {
                Parent = node.Name,
                Name = element
            };
            node.Children.Add(child);
        }
        node = child; // Walk down the tree
    }
}
```

We can test the result with this recursive method:

```cs
private static void PrintChildren(JsonElement node, int level = 0)
{
    string indent = new String(' ', 4 * level);
    foreach (var child in node.Children) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{indent}{child.Name},  Parent = {child.Parent}");
        PrintChildren(child, level + 1);
    }
}
```

Called with `PrintChildren(root);` it prints:

```
address,  Parent =
    city,  Parent = address
        streetname,  Parent = city
            housenumber,  Parent = streetname
            coAddress,  Parent = streetname
    areacode,  Parent = address
person,  Parent =
    name,  Parent = person
        firstname,  Parent = name
        lastname ,  Parent = name
```

See also:

- [Data Structure and Algorithms - Tree](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/tree_data_structure.htm)
- [Tree (data structure)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure))